# p-listbox: search filter textbox does not fit to width

Tags: css, primeng

Working with PrimeNg with the current version 8.0.2 I'm experiencing layout problems with the searchbox inside a listbox. Apparently this was resolved in [3077](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3077).
I've [created a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/listboxexample) so you can see it.

The html code is:

```
<p-listbox [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" multiple="multiple" checkbox="checkbox" filter="filter" optionLabel="name"
[listStyle]="{'max-height':'150px', 'width':'300px'}">
  <p-header>
    Cities
  </p-header>
</p-listbox>
```

Is the bug back? Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the documentation, the problem is mixing the properties `[style]` and `[listStyle]`.

> - style      - Inline style of the container.
> - styleClass  -  Style class of the container.
> - listStyle    - Inline style of    the list element

.

So the inline style should be splited in 2 different attributes:

```
<p-listbox [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" multiple="multiple" checkbox="checkbox" filter="filter" optionLabel="name"
[listStyle]="{'max-height':'150px'}" 
[style]="{'width':'300px'}">
  <p-header>
    Cities
  </p-header>
</p-listbox>
```